# ES6 Destructuring and variable assignment in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6, variable-assignment, destructuring

I'm trying to destructure an object with ES6 syntax then reassign the variable inside a loop.

**ES5**

```
this.playlist.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    item.sound.play()
  }, 1000 * i)
})
```

**ES6 (not working)**

```
this.playlist.forEach(({sound, timeoutId}, i) => {
 timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
   sound.play()
  }, 1000 * i)
})
```

Any idea of why it is not working?

Answer (score 5):

It should work, with one caveat:

```
timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    sound.play()
}, 1000 * i)
```

`timeoutId` is the value inside `item.timeoutId`, and not an alias of it. When you assign a value to `timeoutId`, it won't be assigned back to `item.timeoutId`.

Using `item.timeoutId` to cancel the timeout, won't work, since the `item.timeoutId` won't contain the timeout id.

In the example, you can see that `timeoutId` stays `null`:

```js
const arr=[{ id: 1, timeoutId: null }, { id: 2,timeoutId: null }, { id: 3, timeoutId: null }, { id: 4, timeoutId: null }];

arr.forEach(({sound, timeoutId}, i) => {
 timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
   //sound.play()
  }, 1000 * i)
})

console.log(arr);
```

The solution as noted by @guest271314 is to assign to the property directly, using the the 3rd parameter of the `forEach` (the array), and the index:

```js
const arr=[{ id: 1, timeoutId: null }, { id: 2,timeoutId: null }, { id: 3, timeoutId: null }, { id: 4, timeoutId: null }];

arr.forEach(({sound}, i, arr) => {
 arr[i].timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
   //sound.play()
  }, 1000 * i)
})

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Ok so I'd better stick to ES5 syntax that is much clearer than the one with forEach 3rd parameter. Thanks for your anwser.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because your ES6 code is basically an equivalent to this code:

```
this.playlist.forEach((item, i) => {
  let timeoutId = item.timeoutId;
  let sound = item.sound;
  timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    sound.play()
  }, 1000 * i)
})
```

So you are just reassigning a local variable instead of an `item` object property.

Comment: Thanks, so the destructuring part act as a copy basically and not as a reference.